# ItemUpdating event is not firing

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am new to Sharepoint. I making a conference room booking calendar. My code is working fine when we book any meetings. but when we EDIT the existing booking then my ITEMUPDATING() event is not firing. I have overridden this method in my Event Reciever class.

Previously it was firing this ItemUpdating event. But now suddenly it is not firing. I had inserted a Debugger in ItemUpdating Event but it is not hitting.

Comment: Are you sure the event is not fired? Are you sure that there is no error in your code? Are you handling exceptions? Did you check the Logs?

Comment: @Shoban that event was firing before. But I don't know what has went wrong. And I am very new to his sharepoint. so I don't know the exact solution like can yoy tell me in more detail what measures I should take

Comment: When did it stop? Did you make any coded change? Did you check logs in 12 hive (logs) folder and see if there are any errors.

Comment: I have just checked with SPList.EventReceiver, only one event is been getting registered. when I try to add a new booking. Now <b>can anyone help me out</b>

Comment: Yes I have made many code Changes. but I have one common function FindConlict(). I am just calling this function in ItemAdding and ItemUpdating(). So I have not made any changes in ItemUpdating() event.

Comment: did you change anyting in FindConlict() ? :) even though this is a comon function, if something is changed here and you are calling it in item updating, you have to be sure that this change is not causing the issue.

Comment: Nopes. But I have made again the entire solution i.i Sharepoint Empty Site and followed the same steps. Now it is working. Don't Know waht has gone wrong but for now the issue is solved. may be if i figure out what was wrong i will update

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element.xml file that's attached with the event receiver contain the event in it like :

```
<Receiver>
      <Name>MyDocsEventReceiverItemUpdating</Name>
      <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>SourceSite.MyDocsEventReceiver.MyDocsEventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
</Receiver>
```

As when you override new function in event receiver class VS mayn't add the equivalent xml for it in element.xml file